# Special characters Regex

Tags: c#, special-characters, trim

Hello I'm try to remove special characters from user inputs.

```
        public void fd()
        {
            string output = "";
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();

            foreach (var item in charArray)
            {

                if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(item))
                {

                   \\\CODE HERE                    }

            }

            output = new string(trimmedChars);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

At the end I'm turning it back to a string. My code only removes one special character in the string. Does anyone have any suggestions on a easier way instead

Comment: `int index = Array.IndexOf(charArray, item);` might not be doing what you want it do be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are taking the data from `charArray` and putting the result in `trimmedChars` for each change that you make, so each change will ignore all previous changes and work with the original. At the end you only have the last change.

Another problem with the code is that you are using `IndexOf` to get the index of a character, but that will get the index of the first occurance of that character, not the index where you got that character. For example when you are at the second `!` in the string `"foo!bar!"` you will get the index of the first one.

You don't need to turn the string into an array to work with the characters in the string. You can just loop through the index of the characters in the string.

Note that you should also check the value of the index when you are looking at the characters before and after, so that you don't try to look at characters that are outside the string.

```
public void fd() {
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  int index = 0;
  while (index < input.Length) {
    if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(input, index) && ((index == 0 || !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(input, index - 1)) || (index == input.Length - 1 || !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(input, index + 1)))) {
      input = input.Remove(index, 1);
    } else {
      index++;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct implementation and `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` (forgot about that). This should be accepted

Comment: yes this works perfect the only thing is that if I have two special characters at the end for instance dog$$ it would only remove one and not both

Comment: @CalvinJones this would remove both of them, have you tried it for `dog$$`? I've tried and received `dog`

Comment: @CalvinJones: Check if you have the latest code. I updated the looping, so that it doesn't skip characters when a character is removed.

Comment: ok now it works thanks so much I couldnt figure out exactly what was wrong in my code. Thank you god bless you and your family

Answer (score 4):

You have a nice implementation, just consider using next code, which is only a bit shorter, but has a little bit higher abstractions

```
var input =  " th@ere's! ";

Func<char, bool> isSpecialChar = ch => !char.IsLetter(ch) && !char.IsDigit(ch);

for (int i = 1; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //if current character is a special symbol
    if(isSpecialChar(input[i])) 
    {
        //if previous or next character are special symbols
        if(isSpecialChar(input[i-1]) || isSpecialChar(input[i+1]))
        {
            //remove that character
            input = input.Remove(i, 1);
            //decrease counter, since we removed one char
            i--;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(input); //prints " th@ere's "
```

A new string would be created each time you would call `Remove`. Use a `StringBuilder` for a more memory-performant solution.

Comment: Calling `Remove` on a string doesn't change the string, so the code doesn't do anything. You need to assign the result back to the variable.

Comment: @Guffa it's a `StringBuilder`, `Remove` returns `this` basically

Comment: Sorry, did't see that you used a StringBuilder.

Comment: I tested it out and keeps giving me the same string

Comment: For instance i typed in ap@ple*$ the output was the same instead of ap@ple

Comment: @CalvinJones are you sure you are using StringBuilder? I've change my code to use plain old string, try it out.

Comment: Thank you too for the help you have provided sir god bless you and your family as well for all you have done

Answer (score 0):

Been awhile since I've hit on C#, but a reg ex might be helpful

```
string input = string.Format("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine());
Regex rgx = new Regex("(?i:[^a-z]?)[.](?i:[^a-z]?)");
string output = rgx.Replace(input, "$1$2");
```

The regex looks for a character with a non-alpha character on left or right and replaces it with nothing.

Comment: this actually adds the special character to the string again

Comment: Oh, oops... My 2nd screw up tonight.  Will fix and edit. -- Wait, are you sure?  It should take "a7z" and ignore it, but "a?" and replace it with "a"... Did I miss something?